# Jsoup 1.7.1 SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, jsoup

I am getting this exception with JSoup 1.7.1 on certain SSL URL's.

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors

However when I open up the URL's in an browser it does not give me any security warning. What am I missing?

E.g. URL - https://www.barbican.org.uk/wonder/participation/barbican-weekender

Comment: It means the SSL library's trusted certificates doesn't contain the certificate or any of the parent certificates for that site. It probably means the OS on which JSoup is running has a fairly limited selection of root certificates compared to your computer's.

Comment: Probably true. This is running on Heroku. I am not sure what sort of trusted certificates they have if any. Is there a way I can turn off the trust checking on SSL URLs?

Comment: If you're going to turn off certificate checking, you might as well skip SSL altogether.